# Template Function Instantiation Issues with custom data type

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to create an objects cache of various DB instances , so that only one instance of a DB is stored

```
class objectCache
{
public:
  static inline objectCache& getInstance()
  {
    static objectCache instance;
    return instance;
  }

  template<typename K, typename V>
  Db <K,V> * getDbInstance( string &obj_name );

private:
  objectCache(){};
  objectCache(const objectCache& copy);
  objectCache& operator=(const objectCache& copy);
  map <string,void *> mapObjCache;

};


template<typename K, typename V>
Db <K,V> *
objectCache::getDbInstance( string &Db_name )
{
   Db<K,V> * lookup_db_ptr = NULL;
   string Db_key = "Db_";
   Db_key += Db_name;
   map <string,void *>::iterator it;

   it = mapObjCache.find(Db_key);
   if (  mapObjCache.end() != it  && NULL != mapObjCache[Db_key] )
   {
      lookup_db_ptr = (Db<string,string> *)mapObjCache[Db_key];
      return lookup_db_ptr;
   }
   else
   {
     try{
       lookup_db_ptr = new Db<K,V>(Db_name,O_RDONLY);
     }
     catch(...){lookup_db_ptr = NULL;}
   }


   if ( lookup_db_ptr )
   {
     try{
       mapObjCache[Db_key] = (void *)lookup_db_ptr;
     }
     catch(...)
     {
       delete lookup_db_ptr;
       lookup_db_ptr = NULL;
     }
   }

   return lookup_db_ptr;
}
```

Some how the definition fails when i would like to create objects of custom defined structures.

The below one works

```
db_ptr = (Db<string,string> *) objectCache::getInstance().getDbInstance <string,string> (dbname);
```

while with customized struct type , the following definition fails

```
typedef struct
{
  float val1;
  float val2;
  short int  test1;
  short int  test2;
}myData_t;

myData_t myData;
Db<string,myData_t> *db_ptr;
db_ptr = (Db<string,myData_t> *)
  objectCache::getInstance().getDbInstance <string,myData_t> (dbname);
```

with errors

```
error: cannot convert `Db<std::string, std::string>*' to
  `Db<std::string, myData_t>*' in assignment.
```

Comment: What don't you understand? The error message is pretty clear. Also you don't really want to cast those pointers. Also use C++ style casts. Also why are you using a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here

```
Db<K,V> * lookup_db_ptr = NULL;
```

And then below

```
lookup_db_ptr = (Db<string,string> *)mapObjCache[Db_key];
```

Do you see the error?